# Run Time Error '424' object required on Range

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am testing a command button to run three checks on an internal stock requisition sheet ("TestOrder") in excel 2007. Where the basic premise is that from a list of inventory parts(goods), the user can enter the quantity required of item/s and specify the customer code for who the goods are for. If any of the required fields are empty then a message will appear and the procedure stops.

They must enter their initials as the Requisitioner from a drop down list in one dedicated cell (D2), and select initials of the user who will process the request from another drop down list in the dedicated cell (F2). Quantities will be entered into the appropriate Row of column L, and the customer code in the same row of column M. This sheet will then be filtered and emailed for processing.

I have, in the main got all of that working, but due to time constraints I had not been able to work on a way of checking that all the data required has been entered prior to the filtered order being emailed anywhere.

I need to check three things:

- Step 1, Have both sets of initials been entered
- Step 2, If quantities have been entered, then the customer field cannot be blank
- Step 3, If a customer has been entered then the quantity field cannot be blank.

So, all three steps have to have data in their cells.

I have got Step 1 working as the dedicated cells D2 and F2 do not change, if either cell is blank, a message appears to the user and stops the procedure.

Whereas the quantities required in column L and the customer codes in column M are variable and would be subject to a filter to remove blanks and show only what has been ordered.

So, I was working up a test initially on a single column (M-customer codes) to check if the number of non-empty cells in range is less than total number of cells in range and this is where the Run time error 424 occurred.
On the line

`Set myCellRange = Range("M7:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select`

where M7 is the top cell of the listed data in that column.

My work in progress code is:

```
Sub btn_test_checkdata()
' On the click of this button run a check to see if two cells have the required data, in this case they would be Users Initials selected from a drop down list cell'

If [D2].Value = "" Then
MsgBox "There MUST be Initials selected in the Who is ordering Field", vbOKOnly, "Entry Reqd"
[D2].Select
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If

If [F2].Value = "" Then
MsgBox "There MUST be Initials selected in the Who is the Req'n being sent to Field", vbOKOnly, "Entry Reqd"
[F2].Select
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If

'Sub checkIfAnyCellInRangeIsEmpty()
'declare object variable to hold reference to cell range you work with

Dim myCellRange As Range

'identify cell range you work with
Set myCellRange = Range("M7:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select

'check if number of non-empty cells in range is less than total number of cells in range. Depending on result, display message box indicating whether cell range contains any empty cell (True) or not (False)

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(myCellRange) < myCellRange.Count Then
   MsgBox myCellRange.Address & " contains at least 1 empty cell"

End If
End Sub
```

Obviously, I need to extend this check to both columns so any hints on that would be great, as I'm not an expert user my thinking would have me get the code to work for one column then repeat it for the other.

The current error I'm getting now, has it something to do with specifying the worksheet? As I cannot see me doing that anywhere.

Like I say, I have the main operations working in the order sheet, and this is about me building a small procedure to do a final check before anything else happens.

Comment: If your project involves a workbook with more than 1 worksheet, it is good programming practice to always use something like `ws.Range()` and never a raw `Range()`. Hard to tell if that is the issue here. What happens if you put `Debug.Print "M7:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` prior to the line throwing the error?

Comment: Selecting is an action. It isn't a method which returns a range. Drop the select from that line. If you really want to also select that range, follow it by `myCellRange.Select` -- although good VBA code can almost always avoid `Select`

Comment: (See [How to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba))

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman , so i tried the Debug.Print line prior to the line throwing the error. Took out the '.Select' and added the 'myCellRange.Select' after it. So, when i ran it, no errors were thrown up, my built in error message popped up but what it's done is selected the first value, all the blanks in between that and the last value, and  my error message is looking at that range of blank cells. what it hasn't seen is the missing value from several rows beneath. I think my logic here is in error. How good is the '.End(xlUp)' code going to help if the missing value is beneath.

Comment: I do have a screenshot, but not sure if or how to upload that ?

Comment: In case i need to clarify. I have a table of 50 rows, with columns A-M.So the table data runs A7:M50, the headers sit in row 6. I put data into L7 and M7, L20 and M20, L30 only, wanting my bespoke error message to find that M30 should have data. My bespoke message says "$M$7:$M$20 contains at least 1 empty cell"

Comment: So, working through my logic to ensure the data validation is right, i came up with this IF AND formula and tested it in a cell against a row. '=IF(AND(L7="",M7<>""),"Qty Required",IF(AND(L7<>"",M7=""),"Customer Required",""))' this seems to work out fine. So, my question is, is this better to run through the Data Validation option or would VBA be better?

Answer (score 0):

Move the .Select action:

```vb
    Dim myCellRange As Range
    Set myCellRange = Range("M7:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    myCellRange.Select '<- this action
```